# Polymer: centralize element in core-toolbar

Tags: polymer

I would like to know how can I centralize an element inside a core-toolbar Polymer element. I want it to be in the center of the screen, not in the center of its parent element.

```
<core-header-panel>
    <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
        <paper-icon-button id="menuicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
        <span flex>Company Name</span>      
        <ELEMENT-TO-BE-CENTRALIZED></ELEMENT-TO-BE-CENTRALIZED>
        <paper-icon-button id="searchbutton" icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
    </core-toolbar>
</core-header-panel>
```

I was reading some documentation about alignment (bottom fit and others), but none of them worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another flexible span on the other side of the thing you want to be centered.

```
<core-header-panel>
    <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
        <paper-icon-button id="menuicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
        <span flex>Company Name</span>      
        <ELEMENT-TO-BE-CENTRALIZED></ELEMENT-TO-BE-CENTRALIZED>
        <span flex></span> <!-- I added this -->
        <paper-icon-button id="searchbutton" icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
    </core-toolbar>
</core-header-panel>
```

http://jsbin.com/xorex/2/edit